# How to test a function inside react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that renders tiles and arranges based on the configuration from our configuration server. I have two functions one useEffect hook to render tiles and fetchConfig() to fetches configuration from external server, my question is how can we write testcases for a function that is inside a component?

> StyleWrapper.tsx

```
let fetchConfig = () => {
        await fetch(HOST+"/config/style", {
          method: "GET",
          body: new URLSearchParams(reqParams),
        }).then(async (response) => {
          const styleConfigData = await response.json();
          return styleConfigData;
        });    
};

const StyleWrapper = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function arrangeTiles() {
        // Arrange Tile logic
        return "Tile Arranged"
    }
    arrangeTiles();
  });
  
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ arrangeTiles }}>
      <div id="cnplStyleContainer">{props.children}</div>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default StyleWrapper;
```

Comment: Why your arrangeTiles function is written inside useEffect? and why you have not introduced any dependencies for it? if you can clear things out, it would be much simpler

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're asking, "how can I test a nested function?" The answer is that you can't. The better approach is this: If the function is relatively simple, you should be able to write a satisfying unit test for the function that contains it. If it truly needs to be tested on its own, then make it an exportable function and test it appropriately using e.g. [Jest](https://jestjs.io/).

Additionally, if you're interested in testing `fetchConfig`, I would recommend that you look into [mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions). Unless you're writing an [end-to-end test](https://smartbear.com/solutions/end-to-end-testing/), it's generally inadvisable to rely on network resources in a test scenario.